# cat | xargs mkdir: File name too long?

Tags: macos, shell, xargs, mkdir

I am trying to make directories from a very simple text file list (folders.txt) that looks like this:

```
Homesteader_Droopy_1954
Car_of_Tomorrow_1951
Dixieland_Droopy_1954
Doggone_Tired_1949
Drag_A_Long_Droopy_1954
Droopys_Double_Trouble_1951
```

Using this command:

```
cat folders.txt | xargs mkdir
```

But it keeps spitting out an error that looks like this:

```
mkdir: Homesteader_Droopy_1954\rCar_of_Tomorrow_1951\rDixieland_Droopy_1954\rDoggone_Tired_1949\rDrag_A_Long_Droopy_1954\rDroopys_Double_Trouble_1951: File name too long
```

Any idea why it's adding a `\r` at each new line, and how to get it to stop doing that, and just make the folders?

> OS: Mac Catalina 10.15.7 - zsh 5.7.1

Comment: Not your problem, btw, but avoid `cat file | ...`; it's more efficient to just use `<file` which avoids spinning up a separate `cat` executable. In this case, though, you could -- assuming you have Windows-style CRLFs instead of old-Apple-style CR-only text files --  use `tr -d '\r' <folders.txt | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 mkdir --`; by contrast, if your file is old-Apple-style you'd use `tr '\r' '\0' <folders.txt | xargs -0 mkdir --`

Comment: (using NULs instead of newlines is important there -- xargs behavior is a lot more complex/unintuitive than people think, and it can be very surprising when you have spaces, quotes, &c in your file or directory names)

Comment: ...the error message does imply that the old-Apple style of file may well be what you have, btw. Normally for Windows-style files xargs would treat it as a file `Homesteader_Droopy_1954\r`, then a second file `Car_of_Tomorrow_1951\r` as a second file instead of one big long name.

Comment: (btw, when I say `CR` that's also called `\r`, and a `LF` is also called `\n`, so `CRLF` in one notation is `\r\n` in the other; Windows uses CRLF between lines, pre-OSX Apple systems used CR only, and UNIXy systems including modern MacOS use LF only)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy your second "old Apple style" command worked! You should post it as an answer. `tr '\r' '\0' <folders.txt | xargs -0 mkdir --`